# -How to clear cookies in inappwebview?

Tags: flutter

I'm using fluxstore and apologies as I'm no coder.
I was able to add this line in Webview to clear the cookies and it worked

WebViewCookieManager().clearCookies();

screenshot:
https://tppr.me/xWkoV

however i'm also trying the inappwebview - how do i clear cookies in inappwebview?

thanks!

i tried adding adding the same code in the
webview_inapp.dart file but it didn't work

Comment: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/cookie-manager/

Comment: images are shown as  link